# POSTGRESQL store a gzip or json as text

Tags: postgresql

I need to save a JSON which has a size of about 20 MG (include some jpg base64 images inside).

Is any advantage in performance if I save it on a binary field, JSON field or a text field?
Any suggestion to save it?

Comment: Both `text` and `json` will be compressed whereas binary (`bytea`) will not be compressed if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: But is any perfomande advantage store in byte vs text for example? Tanks!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That's not correct - `bytea` is varlena, and is also TOASTable with compression.

Comment: @CraigRinger: so I _am_ mistaken. Thanks.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Has to happen (very) occasionally ;) . Pretty much all `VARLENA` types are TOASTable, and thus compressible. If you want to be sure for a particular type, check `pg_type.typstorage`. For `bytea` it's e`x`tended, which allows out-of-line and/or compressed storage.

Answer (score 2):

The most efficient way to store this would be to extract the image data, base64-decode it, and store it in a `bytea` field. Then store the rest of the json in a `json` or `text` field. Doing that is likely to save you quite a bit of storage because you're storing the highly compressed JPEG data directly, rather than a base64-encoded version.

If you can't do that, or don't want to, you should just shove the whole lot in a `json` field. PostgreSQL will attempt to compress it, but base64 of a JPEG won't compress too wonderfully with the fast-but-not-very-powerful compression algorithm PostgreSQL uses. So it'll likely be signficantly bigger.

There is no difference in storage terms between `text` and `json`. (`jsonb`, in 9.4, is different - it's optimised for fast access, rather than compact storage).

For example, if I take [this 17.5MB JPEG](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e6/Clocktower_Panorama_20080622_20mb.jpg), it's 18MB as `bytea`. Base64-encoded it's 24MB uncompressed. If I shove that into a `json` field with minimal json syntax wrapping it remains 24MB - which surprised me a little, I expected to save some small amount of storage with `TOAST` compression. Presumably it wasn't considered compressible enough.

(BTW, base64 encoded binary isn't legal as an unmodified json value as you must escape slashes)